# Sortable js error on dragging under capybara spec

Tags: selenium, jquery-ui, rspec, capybara, jquery-ui-sortable

when applying dragging to elements manually in a rspec using executable script :

```
page.execute_script("$('.slide.slid').sortable('option','update')(null, { item:$('#slide_deck_container').appendTo($('.slide.slid')) })")
```

Getting an error:

> Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError Exception: unknown error: cannot call methods on sortable prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'option'
>     (Session info: chrome=56.0.2924.87)
>     (Driver info: chromedriver=2.27.440175 (9bc1d90b8bfa4dd181fbbf769a5eb5e575574320),platform=Linux 3.13.0-32-generic x86_64)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery UI Sortable - Error: cannot call methods on sortable prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'disable'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18305271/jquery-ui-sortable-error-cannot-call-methods-on-sortable-prior-to-initializat)

Comment: Did you google the error message? What did you find? What did you try from those search results to fix the issue?

Answer (score 1):

The error you're getting is pretty self-explanatory: You are trying to call the sortable 'option' method on an element that hasn't been initialized as sortable.  You're either calling it on the wrong element (is $('slid.slid') the actual "sortable" parent element?) or you're calling it before the page has initialized.  If the first then you need to call it on the correct element, if the second then you need to set an expectation for something that appears on the page to show it is initialized so Capybara will wait for it, or sleep for a couple of seconds to allow the page time to initialize.